# How to set header information

Tags: java, javascript, html, http, header

I have a piece of Java code which tries to access the header information posted by an html page.Right now I don't have the html page but I need to access the header information in the java file details.Can anyone please help me in writing a html page which sets header information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the some sample meta data tags syntax:

```
 <META NAME="description" CONTENT="A description of HTML 4.0's META element for metadata.">
    <META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="META, meta element, metadata">
```

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/head/meta.html

Answer (score 1):

Headers cannot be changed by a plain html file.

What you are trying to achieve though may be doable via "meta http-equiv" directives. So, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged it javascript: Use an AJAX request. You can use the `setRequestHeader(header, value)` [method of XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XmlHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("HeaderName", "value");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: I can't use AJAX.I want only synchronous Javascript.

Comment: You can make the xhr synchronous by calling the `open` with the third parameter (async) set to `false`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29